# Shell script on MacOS freezes when trigged with launchd

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-s3, macos-monterey

This is a strange one.

I have a bash script (let's call it fileChecker.sh) that loops through a directory of files. It checks each file, sends parameters for each to another bash script (uploadToS3.sh) which uploads them to an S3 bucket. The fileChecker.sh triggers the uploadToS3.sh and does not wait for it to finish (I believe this is called forking???). Snippet from the fileChecker.sh triggering the uploadToS3.sh:

```
sh ("/Users/Shared/Scripts/uploadToS3.sh" "$thefilepath" "$s3" "$thefilename" "$filenameExtension") &
```

The uploadToS3.sh script uses python and s3cmd to upload the file to the s3 bucket. Snippet from the script:

```
/usr/local/bin/s3cmd --access_key=$s3AccessKey --secret_key=$s3SecretKey --region=$s3Region --progress put "$thefilepath" "$s3Path""$thefilename"
```

The Problem: both scripts execute without issue when run manually from an IDE but I need it to run on time intervals every 30 seconds. When I run it with launchd, /Library/LaunchAgents/, the first script (fileChecker.sh) completes without issue. Each execution of the uploadToS3.sh is triggered successfully but never finishes. To be more specific, I check the output from each instance of the uploadToS3.sh and each file starts to upload to the s3 bucket then stops. There are no errors to be found in the stderr. The stdout just has the first details of the upload process.

Any thoughts? I'm happy to add more of the code and more detail if needed. Been stuck on this for a week now and could use any help I can get.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're tripping over a feature of launchd that's intended to be helpful, but sometimes causes problems like this: when a daemon or agent exits, launchd will "clean up" (i.e. kill) any leftover subprocesses. It sounds like when fileChecker.sh exits, launchd kills uploadToS3.sh before it has a chance to finish.

Fortunately, this is easy to fix. Add `<key>AbandonProcessGroup</key><true/>` to the launchd .plist file to disable this behavior.